# Firebase v3 - Web SDK ref.child gone?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Where did `ref.child()` go, and if gone, why?  What is the replacement?

I used to be able to say `var colors = ref.child("colors");` , for example, but this no longer works.  Is the replacement

```
var ref = firebase.database();
var myVar = ref('colors');
```

??

Answer (score 0):

...nevermind.  I figured it out.  You have to now do:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
var colors = ref.child("colors");
```